# Show enum constants in Visual Studio from a DLL with PDB

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, dll, pdb-files

I am debugging a process that uses some DLLs, I don't have their code but got their PDBs which I have loaded into the debugger. I set a function breakpoint to a DLL export function `HadleTypedError(...)` and it worked flawlessly. In `Locals` window I see an object that has a enum field which value's name is correctly decoded by the debugger. It looks like this:

```
errorDesc:      0x00007fff800010000                  SErrorDesc
code:           VALUE_MUST_BE_IN_TABLE(3)            SErrorDesc::EErrorCode
...
```

So the debugger know that `errorDesc.code` which is `3` is actually a enum constant `SErrorDesc::EErrorCode::VALUE_MUST_BE_IN_TABLE`.

Can I output other enum constant using the debugger?

Comment: Open the Watch window, and enter an expression that has the value you wish to see, and cast it to the enumerated type.

Comment: See [Use expressions in a Watch window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows#use-expressions-in-a-watch-window) as well as [Expressions in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger) for details.

Comment: @IInspectable yeah casting (e.g. `(SErrorDesc::EErrorCode)0, 1, 2 ... N`) works but is it possible to output an entire enum? These constants are in the PDB, no doubt, is it possible to list them?

Comment: There is no such thing as *"an entire enum"* in C++. Any value that has a valid encoding in the underlying type is a valid enum value, even if it doesn't have a name.

Comment: @IInspectable that's absolutely true in run time without symbols. But the PDB (the program database) contains information about "how to interpret a certain value (a specific pointer or integer)" so if the debugger can find a corresponding enum constant for a given integer value, maybe I can find all of them for type that is also stored in the PDB (`SErrorDesc::EErrorCode`)?

Comment: You probably can, but I'm not aware of a way to do this in Visual Studio. WinDbg's scriptability might be able to do this. It that doesn't help you can use the [Debug Help Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/debug-help-library) or the [Debug Interface Access SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk).

Comment: @IInspectable thank you! I'll take a look, if no one come up with something better, I'll write an answer myself.

Comment: In cdb/WinDbg the command [dt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dt--display-type-) does exactly that, but it looks like it's not available in Visual Studio.